# Soundcloud getting tracks php+js

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

I'm going to get track on my site from soundcloud. I'm working according to [official tutorial](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication).
Well, I created app in soundcloud, got cliend_id and client secret. Also I've created callback.php and showed it as redirect_uri in app settings of soundcloud. Here it's content.

```
<?php
require_once './Services/Soundcloud.php';
// my_client_id and my_client_secret are my but I'm not sure what should be instead of http://example.com/callback so I just left it here.
$client = new Services_Soundcloud(
  'my_client_id', 'my_client_secret', 'http://example.com/callback');
var_dump($client);
echo'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>';

// redirect user to authorize URL
//header("Location: " . $client->getAuthorizeUrl());
?>
```

Also here is my main .js script fragment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: 'my_client_id',
      redirect_uri: 'http://sscopin.temp.swtest.ru/radio%20for%20upload/Derpman/callback.php'
    });

        // initiate auth popup
    SC.connect(function() {
          SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
            alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
          });
        });         
});
```

So I used my callback.php as redirect_uri when initializing SC

So I get some strange results. I got popud window with soundcloud login. And when I enter my login/password I get my page. I can watch dump of $client and message but if I uncomment string:

```
header("Location: " . $client->getAuthorizeUrl());
```

I get cyclic forwarding error. So what's wrong? What should I use as redicrect uri in javascript, php and soundcloud app settings? That's not clear at all for me.

Comment: are u sure u wanna mix php and js?

Comment: Well, why not? What's your suggestions? Is it necessary for some reasons use Ruby or Python?

Comment: i would recommend to use php or js - but sure its up to you and your app.

Comment: by using js, you have to host the callback.html on your server. actually you refer to a different file, right?

Comment: Oh, dude, thanx. I thought that it's like server-side of application and client side of it. Of course I'll use only one of them.
If you want you can answer my question, however it was asked because of inattention. If not I'll just delete it. Dunno if someone can run into same problem.